# A question about the gradient of function with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Let $f\in C^2_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a function, where $C^2_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the set of function that are twice continuously differentiable with compact support.

**Notation.** We denote with $\nabla f$ the gradient of function $f$.

I must prove that

> $$\lvert \nabla f(x) \rvert \le C\left(\rVert \nabla f \lVert _{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}  \right),$$ that is $\lvert \nabla f \rvert$ is dominated by a costant that depends of $L^\infty-$ norm of its gradient.

*Proof*

$$\lvert \nabla f(x) \rvert \le \rVert \nabla f\lVert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R^n})}=\text{esssup}_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\lvert \nabla f(x)\rvert=\sup_{\mathbb{R}^n}\lvert \nabla f(x)\rvert=\sup_{\text{supp(f)}}\lvert \nabla f(x)\rvert<\infty\tag1,$$
where I use the fact that $\nabla f$ is continuous function and the Weierstrass theorem combined with the fact that the support of $f$ is compact.

> Is my approach correct? Thank you for your patience and attention.

Comment: Yes, although the order you write the estimates in is a bit strange. By definition $|\nabla f(x)|\leq \sup_{\mathbb{R^n}} |\nabla f|$ and then due to continuity $\sup_{\mathbb{R^n}}|\nabla f|= \|\nabla f\|_{L^\infty}$.